# Execution Redirects to Unwanted Action Method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC project that uses forms authentication. When user click login button, the code section below in the controller has being called:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> OturumAc(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //OturumAcmaSonuc = ResultOfLogin, sonuc = result
    OturumAcmaSonuc sonuc = null;
    //Kullanici = User
    Kullanici kullanicisi = null;
    //Anasayfa = MainPage
    AnasayfaViewModel anasayfaModel = null;
    PersonelViewModel personelvm = null;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    try
    {
        personelvm = new PersonelViewModel();

        //AcOturum  = Login
        sonuc = this._personelik.AcOturum(model);

        // OturumAcmaSonucu = CanSheLogin
        if (sonuc.OturumAcmaSonucu)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sonuc.Kullanicisi.KullaniciAdi, false);
            kullanicisi = sonuc.Kullanicisi;
            //Depola = Store
            this._cache.Depola(CacheDepolamaEnum.Kullanici, kullanicisi);

            anasayfaModel = new AnasayfaViewModel(sonuc.Mesaj, kullanicisi);                
            //Depola = Store
            this._cache.Depola(CacheDepolamaEnum.AnasayfaViewModel, anasayfaModel);
            //Anasayfa = MainPage
            return RedirectToAction("Anasayfa", "Account");

        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Hata"] = SistemMesajlar.BasarisizOturumAcma();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Hata)
    {
        this._hataik.YazHata(Hata);
    }

    return View(model);     

}
```

This action method shall be the ultimate method for login. As you expected, when the result of login is true, the execution is expected to branch out to "Anasayfa" (MainPage) action method, however it branch out to "Login" action method. This is the error. Here is the content of the web.config of the web layer:

```
 <system.web>
<globalization uiCulture="tr-TR" culture="tr-TR" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Account/OturumAc" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Error" mode="On">
</customErrors>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
```

when I write the "Login" action method as described below, It branch out to Login.cshtml:

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

When I remove the [AllowAnonymous] tag, it gets "The request filtering module query string is configured to be too long." the requested url is : " http://localhost:29736/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAnasayfa"

I try to find two solutions :

1-) Whenever a user successfully logins, it shall branch out to "Anasayfa" (MainPage) action method.
1-) Execution shall not branch out to "Login" action method, it shall branch out "OturumAc" action method.

How can I overcome these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does redirect to the `Anasayfa()` method (that's what `return RedirectToAction("Anasayfa", "Account");` will do). If is displaying the `Login` page, then either `ModelState` is invalid or `sonuc.OturumAcmaSonucu` is `false` or your code throws an exception

Comment: Dear Stephen; I debug the code, (including Application_Error in Global.asax)1-) There is no ModelState error, 2- )  sonuc.OturumAcmaSonucu is true and 3-) I can not observe any exception.

Comment: I have found a solution. 
I go to Startup partial class in App_Start folder in the MVC project, there was a line : LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"), to  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/OturumAc") and I change  return RedirectToAction("Anasayfa", "Account"); to return View("Anasayfa") and the problem is okey. I wonder why RedirectToAction fails there.

Comment: is your "Anasayfa" action placed in "Account" controller?

Comment: [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Anasayfa()
        {
            AnasayfaViewModel model = null;
            try
            {
                model = this._cache.EldeEt<AnasayfaViewModel>(CacheDepolamaEnum.AnasayfaViewModel);
                if (model == null)
                {
                    model = new AnasayfaViewModel();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception hata)
            {

                this._hataik.YazHata(hata);
                model = new AnasayfaViewModel();
            }

            return View(model);
        }